# Wifiidog iptables rules

Tags: iptables, wifi

Trying to get a wifidog installation working. We had it up, but when rewriting bash history into an install script, we keep running into problems with iptables.

```
[root@wifidogdevel ~]# iptables -t mangle -D WiFiDog_eth1_Outgoing -s 192.168.1.254 -m mac --mac-source 00:24:E8:B6:18:A2 -j MARK --set-mark 2
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name
```

But:

```
iptables -L -t mangle
[...]
Chain WiFiDog_eth1_Outgoing (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

iptables -L -t nat
[...]
Chain WiFiDog_eth1_Outgoing (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
WiFiDog_eth1_WIFI2Router  all  --  anywhere             192.168.1.1         
WiFiDog_eth1_WIFI2Internet  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Which to me says there is indeed a chain and target by that name. So, what am I missing for the match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that there is a chain and target by that name, but in the output above, there is not.  Your command is an instruction to delete from the chain `WiFiDog_eth1_Outgoing`, in the mangle table, the rule

```
-s 192.168.1.254 -m mac --mac-source 00:24:E8:B6:18:A2 -j MARK --set-mark 2
```

but according to your iptables -L output, there are no rules in the chain `WiFiDog_eth1_Outgoing`, in the mangle table.  iptables therefore quite rightly complains that it cannot delete the rule from that chain and table, because it doesn't exist.

You might want to consider **not** duplicating a chain name across multiple tables - it seems likely to lead to confusion!